# Trim columns in CSV with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that contains multiple columns, and I only need two with headers "address" and "port. I'm trying this simple function with Panda, but getting errors. Any ideas what the issue is? Thanks.

The input file has columns with headers: Start Time, End time, address, vendor, hostname,port, state, service, script,  output

```
import pandas as pd
def trim_scan(infile, outdir):

    df = pd.read_csv(infile)
    keep_cols = ["address", "port"]
    new_df = df[keep_cols]
    new_df.to_csv(outdir + '/' + 'nmap-ip-ports.csv', index=False)

trim_scan('nmap-scan.csv', '2015-07-27')
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 64, in <module>
    trim_scan('nmap-scan.csv', '2015-07-27')
  File "test3.py", line 59, in trim_scan
    df = pd.read_csv(infile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 474, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 260, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 721, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1170, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 769, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7544)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 791, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:7784)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 844, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8401)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 831, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8275)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1742, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:20691)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 6, saw 14
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from you CSV file which is not regular (not the same number of fields at every line).

```
Expected 12 fields in line 6, saw 14
```

Another hint about your ill-formed CSV file is also given by the fact that you defined 10 different fields:

```
Start Time, End time, address, vendor, hostname, port, state, service, script, output
```

But pandas expects 12.

You can check the format of your timestamps or any other field which includes a `;` in its value. Check for headers, skip bad rows, etc.